# php codeigniter insert query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

In my php codeigniter insert query no any error. If get the query and manually execute that query work well. I can't understand why my insertion query is not working.

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$res = $this->db->insert('corporate_user_invite', $sdata);
print_r($this->db->last_query());
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must commit the changes before closing the transaction.

```
    $this->db->trans_commit();
```

Comment: thank you, Now It is correct